# JAVA speed up List filtering

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have one initial List with Subjects and Phrases for each subject.

```
public class Subject {
    private String subject_name;
    private List<Phrase> phrases;
}

public class Phrase {
    private String phrase_name; 
}
```

I need to filter initial subjects list (**should get another list**), the condition is that phrases name should match words in input text. 
So if I have as input List:

```
subjects :
[
    {
        subject_name : "black",
        phrases : 
        [
            phrase_name : "one",
            phrase_name : "two",
            phrase_name : "three"       
        ]
    },
    {
        subject_name : "white",
        phrases : 
        [
            phrase_name : "qw",
            phrase_name : "as",
            phrase_name : "do",
            phrase_name : "oopopop"
        ]
    },
    {
        subject_name : "green",
        phrases : 
        [
            phrase_name : "rrr",
            phrase_name : "ppo" 
        ]
    }
]
```

and I have as input text = `"one year today some rrr"`, finally I need to get the following List

```
subjects :
[
    {
        subject_name : "black",
        phrases : 
        [
            phrase_name : "one"
        ]
    },
    {
        subject_name : "green",
        phrases : 
        [
            phrase_name : "rrr" 
        ]
    }
]
```

The code below work fine and I get the desired result, but it slow when I need to filter for example 20000 "text" for subjects that take me some times ~ 5min, depending on text size.

```
private List<Subject> filterSubjects(List<Subject> subjects, String text) {
    List<Subject> result = new ArrayList<Subject>();

    for (Subject subject : subjects) {

        List<Phrase> p = new ArrayList<Phrase>();
        for (Phrase phrase : subject.getPhrases()) {
            String regex = "\\b(" + replaceSpecialChars(phrase.getName()).toLowerCase() + ")\\b";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

            if (matcher.find()) {
                p.add(phrase);
            }
        }

        if (!p.isEmpty()) {
            result.add(new Subject.SubjectBuilder(subject.getSubjectId(), subject.getName())
                    .setWeight(subject.getWeight()).setColor(subject.getColor())
                    .setOntologyId(subject.getOntologyId()).setCreatedBy(subject.getCreatedBy())
                    .setUpdatedBy(subject.getUpdatedBy()).setPhrases(p).build());

        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I also tried with streams, but that does not work for me since I dont want to filter initial subject list, but need get a new one:

```
subjects = subjects.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.getPhrases().parallelStream()
                .anyMatch(p -> text.matches(".*\\b" + replaceSpecialChars(p.getName().toLowerCase()) + "\\b.*")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

subjects.parallelStream()
        .forEach(s -> s.getPhrases().removeIf(p -> !text.matches(".*\\b"
                + replaceSpecialChars(p.getName().toLowerCase())
                + "\\b.*")));
```

**EDIT**

here is the result of the profiling

[image]

Comment: Have you profiled it to see what's the biggest hotspot?

Comment: I just did and the whole time is consumed by that method. on second place is replaceSpecialChars.

Comment: Regex probably isn't the best option here. [Use a JSON parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java).

Comment: Why I need to use JSON parser. I have a Collection of Subjects ! Just saw in JSON format as example of what I have as input

Comment: The only thing I would suggest from looking at your code snippet is trying to preallocate the `ArrayList` if you can heuristically estimate its average size, e.g. init it with an initial capacity of half of the subjects amount: `new ArrayList<Subject>(subjects.size() / 2);` This could speed up the appending of elements. Or use some other list impl like `LinkedList`...

Comment: By what method? The entire `filterSubjects`? Of course, but what are the methods *inside* it that take the most time.

Comment: @hoefling Maybe not `LinkedList` (it's quite slow unfortunately), but if the resizing is problem, yeah it's probably a better idea to go with more than the default `10` sized `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll default the List size at the beginning. @Kayaman Regarding the profiling which method are take most time - in visualVM I see just the whole filterSubjects that is time consuming and not split

Comment: @DumitruGutu: you can introduce temporary methods, e.g. extract the inner loop in the `List<Phrase> filterPhrases(Subject subj, String text);` and then measure the elapsing time more efficiently.

Comment: @DumitruGutu: Another suggestion would be string interning after parsing (`String.intern`) if you have many duplicate texts.

Answer (score 4):

As was suggested in the comments, you should profile. Properly used, a profiler should give you more detail than "the whole time is consumed in that method". You should be able to see how much time is spent in `Pattern.compile()`, `Matcher.find()`, `ArrayList.add()` and all the other methods, whether they're yours or JDK methods.

It's absolutely crucial that you do this, otherwise you are wasting effort by working blind. For example, maybe `ArrayList.add()` is taking the time. You could solve it in various ways. But why spend time on that unless you have solid evidence that this is where the problem is?

You could also apply the *extract method* refactoring, so that you have more of your own methods for the profiler to report on. A bonus of this is that compilers and runtimes are great at optimising small methods.

When you've found the method where the time is being spent you need to either:

- make that method more efficient
- find a way to call that method fewer times

If it's spending a lot of time in `replaceSpecialChars()`, you should take a look at that, and improve its performance.

Depending on their complexity, compiling regex can take time. If `replaceSpecialChars()` has a `Pattern.compile()` in it, move it somewhere it will only get invoked once (a static initializer, constructor, etc.). If it uses regex and doesn't have `Pattern.compile()`, consider introducing one.

**Your edit shows that most of the time is spent in `Pattern.compile()` invoked by the code you've showed us.**

Because your `regex` in the code you've shown us is built using a string from the data, you can't just call `Pattern.compile()` once. However, you might benefit from memoising repeated phrases -- the value of this depends on how much repetition there is in the data.

---

```
 Map<String, Pattern> patterns = new HashMap<>();

 Pattern pattern(String s) {
     Pattern pattern = patterns.get(s);
     if(pattern == null) {
         pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + s + "\\b");
         patterns.put(s,pattern);
     }
     return pattern;
 }
```

(Note this is not thread-safe -- there are better cache classes, for example in Guava)

---

You could make the find-within-text easier, by preparing it (once per input):

- convert all boundary characters to a space
- add a space at the front and back

Now you only need `preparedText.contains(" " + phrase.getName() + " ")`. This avoids compiling a regex altogether. You might use a regex to prepare the text, but this only has to be done once (and if you have more than one text, you can reused the compiled `Pattern`.

But if you're doing that you might as well process the text into a `Set` that's faster to search than a String:

```
Set<String> wordSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(preparedText.split(" ")));
```

`wordSet.contains(phrase.getName())` should be faster than `preparedText.contains(phrase.getName())`, for large enough texts.

---

It may also -- again, depending on the data -- be faster iterate through the tokens in `text`, looking for words in a set, than it is to loop through the words. This may return the items in a different order -- whether this is important depends on your requirement.

```
 Set<String> lookingFor = collectWordsToFind(subject);
 StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(text);
 for(String token : tokens) {
     if(lookingFor.contains(token)) {  // or if(lookingFor.remove(token))
          outputlist.add(token);
     }
 }
```

This avoids scanning through each `text` more than once.

---

Finally, stepping right back, I would consider first pre-processing the `Subject` data, making a map of `phrase_name` to `Subject`. Maybe you're already reading your data from an external source -- if so, by all means build this map as you read (perhaps instead of the List you currently have):

```
Map<String,Set<Subject>> map = new HashMap<>();
for(Subject subject : subjects) {
    for(String phrase : subject.phrases()) {
        String name = phrase.name();
        Set<Subject> subjectsForName = map.get(name);
        if(subjectsForName == null) {
            subjectsForName = new HashSet<>();
            map.put(name, subjectsForName);
        }
        subjectsForName.add(subject);
    }
}
```

Now for each word in your input `text`, you can quickly get a set of Subjects containing that phrase_name, `Set<Subjects> subjectsForThisWord = map.get(word)`.

`Map<T,Collection<U>>` is a fairly common pattern, but third party collection libraries like Guava and Apache Commons provide `MultiMap` that does the same thing with a cleaner API.

Comment: seems that Pattern.compile get the most time of the method

Comment: using Set for the text does not work for me since the "phrase" name can be combination of words (one, two, three words, etc). Seems text.contains is right solution here

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that you tried streams with no luck, here is my attempt to convert your function to streams (**WARNING**: untested!):

```java
subjects.parallelStream()
            .map(subject -> {
                List<Phrase> filteredPhrases = subject.getPhrases().parallelStream()
                        .filter(p -> text.matches(".*\\b" + replaceSpecialChars(p.getName().toLowerCase()) + "\\b.*"))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(subject, filteredPhrases);
            })
            .filter(entry -> !entry.getValue().isEmpty())
            .map(entry -> {
                Subject subj = entry.getKey();
                List<Phrase> filteredPhrases = entry.getValue();
                return new Subject.SubjectBuilder(subj.getId(), subj.getName()).setWeight(subj.getWeight()).setPhrases(filteredPhrases);
            })
            .map(Subject.SubjectBuilder::build)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Basically, the first map is to build a pair of your original subject and the filtered phrases, in the second map those pairs are mapped to a single `SubjectBuilder` instance with all the parameters initialized (also notice that instead of the original phrases, the filtered ones are passed), the third map in then just the building of new subjects.

I'm not sure if this code will be any faster than yours (also I did not test it, so no warranties whatsoever!), it's merely an idea for you how your task can be solved with streams.

Answer (score 1):

The more different words you have to find, the less it pays off to perform a distinct regex matching. Besides the preparation costs for each distinct regex, you are performing a new linear search operation for every word. Instead, let the engine match *whole words* only and perform a fast map lookup for the words.

First, prepare a lookup map

```
Map<String,Map.Entry<Phrase,Subject>> lookup = subject.stream()
  .flatMap(s->s.getPhrases().stream().map(p->new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(p,s)))
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().getName(), Function.identity()));
```

Then, use the regex engine to stream over the whole words and lookup their associated `Subject`/`Phrase` combination, group by the `Subject`s and convert the resulting groups to the new `Subject`s afterwards:

```
List<Subject> result =
    Pattern.compile("\\W+").splitAsStream(text)
           .map(lookup::get)
           .filter(Objects::nonNull)
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
                      Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())))
           .entrySet().stream()
           .map(e -> {
             Subject subject=e.getKey();
             return new Subject.SubjectBuilder(subject.getSubjectId(), subject.getName())
               .setWeight(subject.getWeight()).setColor(subject.getColor())
               .setOntologyId(subject.getOntologyId()).setCreatedBy(subject.getCreatedBy())
               .setUpdatedBy(subject.getUpdatedBy()).setPhrases(e.getValue()).build();
           })
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It would be much simpler if `Subject.SubjectBuilder` supports specifying the existing `Subject` as template instead of having to copy each property manually…

Comment: Looking over it, you likely want to to `Pattern.compile("\\W+").splitAsStream(text).distinct() …`…

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you can't get rid of the for loops (which are an absolute killer for code complexity), since you need to check every subject (even if you sorted the subjects prior to filtering). So, the only possible acceleration in my opinion could be done by multithreading (if you don't care about the order in the output list). For that, you can use java's built-in `ExecutorService`. it will spawn a specified number of threads, you submit all of the filtering tasks and the ExecutorService automatically dispatches them among the threads.

**Edit:** You might also want to make sure that your `SubjectBuilder` does not create a copy of `p` since this can take a big amount of time, too.

Answer (score 0):

I would try getting rid of the regex, since you are compiling these for every phrase in every subject.  I'm not sure it would be much more efficient, or achieves exactly the same results, since I can't run it against your dataset but you could try a change like this:

```
        List<Phrase> p = new ArrayList<Phrase>();
        for (Phrase phrase : subject.getPhrases()) {
            //String regex = "\\b(" + phrase.getName().toLowerCase() + ")\\b";
            //Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
            //Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
            //
            //if (matcher.find()) {
            //    p.add(phrase);
            //}
            if (text.contains(phrase.getName().toLowerCase())) {
                p.add(phrase);
            }
        }
```

I did a basic test and I think it should match in a similar manner

Comment: contains does not work, since I need to check my whole words and not that's string is part of another string. so the rule is that words from phrases are part of the text

Comment: @DumitruGutu sorry could you provide an example? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be very simple using "contains" instead of using Pattern that consume the most processing time:

```
private List<Subject> filterSubjects(List<Subject> subjects, String text) {

    String SPACE_PATTERN = " ";
    List<Subject> result = new ArrayList<Subject>();

    for (Subject subject : subjects) {

        List<Phrase> p = new ArrayList<Phrase>();
        for (Phrase phrase : subject.getPhrases()) {        
            if (text.contains(SPACE_PATTERN + replaceSpecialChars(phrase.getName()).toLowerCase() + SPACE_PATTERN)) {
                p.add(phrase);
            }
        }

        if (!p.isEmpty()) {
            result.add(new Subject.SubjectBuilder(subject.getSubjectId(), subject.getName())
                    .setWeight(subject.getWeight()).setColor(subject.getColor())
                    .setOntologyId(subject.getOntologyId()).setCreatedBy(subject.getCreatedBy())
                    .setUpdatedBy(subject.getUpdatedBy()).setPhrases(p).build());

        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

That give me performance from ~ 5 minutes before and now ~ 20 seconds for 20K text to process. The another step that I'll optimize is to take out `replaceSpecialChars` from loop for the phrases names

Comment: Good job! I think there is a suggestion provided by @slim should be adopted. Using set:
`Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(text.split(" "))); if (set.contains(phrase.getName()) || set.contains(replaceSpecialChars(phrase.getName()).toLowerCase())) {...}`